# Strange result/SQL output from Laravel Eloquent using relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a user model as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userId';
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $fillable  = [
        'name',
        'email'
    ];

    public function address(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }

}
```

I've got an Address Model here:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'address';
    protected $primaryKey = 'addressId';
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $fillable  = [
        'addressLine1',
        'addressLine2,
        'county',
        'postcode'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've defined relationships as explained on: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships

I'm supposed to get a list of addresses for a user by using:

```
$this->userModel->address()->where('userId', $userLoginData['userId'])->get();
```

The result is a blank array so I ran:

```
$this->userModel->address()->where('userId', $userLoginData['userId'])->toSql();
```

The output it produces is

```
select * from `address` where `address`.`userId` is null and `address`.`userId` is not null and `userId` =
?
```

Why is it producing a NULL check and a NOT null check.  Obviously the results are empty as they can't be both.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the `dd($this->userModel)`? Is it an instance of the User class or something else? Also if you can share the DB schema for the User and Address tables.

Comment: Your User model also has this `protected $primaryKey = 'userIdId';` is the primary key actually `userIdId`? Please confirm.

Comment: DD is below:
`code`
#connection: null
  #table: "user"
  #primaryKey: "userId"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: false
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []

Comment: No, primary key is userId (was a typo before)

Comment: In this case - please share some more of the code encapsulating `$this->userModel->address()->where('userId', $userLoginData['userId'])->get();` please. Edit your question above and add it.

Comment: Your query makes no sense, assuming `$this->userModel` is an instance of `User`. The first part of the statement `$this->userModel->address()` says you want addresses belonging to the user, but the second part `->where('userId', $userLoginData['userId'])` says you want addresses belonging to some other id.

Comment: Also you are way off-model with your naming conventions. If another dev with any Laravel experience ever has to work on this codebase they will not be impressed. You are purposefully obfuscating information by hiding many addresses behind a singular name. Table name: `users`; primary key: `id`; relationship name: `addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the foreignkey in the relationship on the `User` model for the `address`

like:

```php
public function address(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'userId');
}
```

Comment: I actually had that originally but removed it thinking it may be causing an issue.  It's worth noting that the reverse and querying the address model works fine.  Just a bit stumped on why the parent hasMany doesn't work.